# Remove Element From Struct But Only For This One Function

Tags: go

So I have an Struct that holds data that has a `AddedByUser` which links to my User Struct.

What I want to be able to do it remove the `UserLevel` from the `AddedByUser`

Now I want to be able to do it from this function only, so using the `json:"-"` is not an option. That would remove it from all json output. I only want to remove it form this one function.

I should also say that these are Gorm models and when I have been trying to remove the `10` option (UserLevels) it only removes the outer data set not the UserLevel from all of the data.

```
{
    "ID": 1,
    "CreatedAt": "2019-01-08T16:33:09.514711Z",
    "UpdatedAt": "2019-01-08T16:33:09.514711Z",
    "DeletedAt": null,
    "UUID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "Title": "title000",
    "Information": "info999",
    "EventDate": "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z",
    "AddedByUser": {
        "ID": 2,
        "CreatedAt": "2019-01-08T15:27:52.435397Z",
        "UpdatedAt": "2019-01-08T15:27:52.435397Z",
        "DeletedAt": null,
        "UUID": "b019df80-a7e4-4397-814a-795e7e84b4ca",
        "Firstname": "Me",
        "Surname": "admin",
        "Password": "....",
        "Email": "admin@email.co.uk",
        "UserLevel": {
            "ID": 0,
            "CreatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "UpdatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "DeletedAt": null,
            "LevelTitle": "",
            "UserLevel": null
        },
```

So this is what I have tried,

```
data := []models.MyData{}
data = append(data[0:2])
```

I have about 14 results, with out the append it loads all the results but with this is only loads two results. The idea was to remove either `UpdateAt` or `Title`. As I am not sure if the gorm model information is all 0 or if the slice sees them as 0,1,2,3,4 etc.

I have also tried to range over the slice of models, while I can access each of the sections, I can not seem to find a simple method to remove data by name from a struct? Maps seem to have that but not structs which I am not sure why?

Thanks.

UPDATE

This is the model I am using:

```
//Model
type MyData struct {
  gorm.Model
  UUID              uuid.UUID
  Title       string
  Information string
  EventDate       time.Time

  AddedByUser   Users `gorm:"ForeignKey:added_by_user_fk"`
  AddedByUserFK uint
 }

//Users Model
type Users struct {
  gorm.Model
  UUID      uuid.UUID
  Firstname string
  Surname   string
  Password  string
  Email     string

  UserLevel   UserLevels `gorm:"ForeignKey:user_level_fk" json:",omitempty"`
  UserLevelFK uint
}
```

Comment: You cannot remove a field from a struct value because that's part of its type. You can, however, set it to its zero value.

Comment: Is that part of Go? Becuase thats just dumb, I should be able to control the flow of information out, per function and not just either all or nothing

Comment: That is part of every statically typed language, not just Go. You should add your type definitions to the question to get concrete solutions to your problem.

Comment: what about building another struct? without the levels added and then importing only what I want to display? Not sure if thats possible?

Comment: Question updated with a copy of the struct I am using & now updated with users model as well :)

Comment: Of course that's possible, and it is a valid solution. If this is the simplest solution depends on your type definitions, though, which is why you should add them to the question. Include the `Users` type too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you cannot remove fields from a struct value, because that would yield a value of a different type.

However, you can set fields to their zero value. Combined with the `omitempty` JSON tag, you can exclude fields from the JSON encoding. To make this work properly, you have to change the `UserLevel` field to a pointer type (otherwise you end up with empty objects in the JSON document).

Types shortened for brevity:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type MyData struct {
    Title       string
    AddedByUser Users
}

type Users struct {
    ID        int
    UserLevel *UserLevels `json:",omitempty"` // pointer type with omitempty
}

type UserLevels struct {
    LevelTitle string
}

func main() {
    var x MyData
    x.Title = "foo"
    x.AddedByUser.ID = 2
    x.AddedByUser.UserLevel = &UserLevels{}

    f(x)

    b, _ := json.MarshalIndent(x, "", "  ")
    fmt.Println("main:\n" + string(b))
}

func f(x MyData) {
    // "unset" UserLevel. Since we are receiving a copy of MyData, this is
    // invisible to the caller.
    x.AddedByUser.UserLevel = nil

    b, _ := json.MarshalIndent(x, "", "  ")
    fmt.Println("f:\n" + string(b))
}

// Output:
// f:
// {
//   "Title": "foo",
//   "AddedByUser": {
//     "ID": 2
//   }
// }
// main:
// {
//   "Title": "foo",
//   "AddedByUser": {
//     "ID": 2,
//     "UserLevel": {
//       "LevelTitle": ""
//     }
//   }
// }
```

Try it on the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/trUgnYamVOA

Alternatively, you can define new types that exclude the AddedByUser field. However, since this field isn't at the top level, this is a lot of work, and it's easy to forget to update those types when new fields are added to the original types.

If the field were at the top level, the compiler would do most of the work for you, because types that only differ in their field tags can be directly converted to one another:

```
type MyData struct {
    ID    int
    Title string
}

func main() {
    var x MyData
    x.ID = 1
    x.Title = "foo"

    f(x)
}

func f(x MyData) {
    type data struct { // same as MyData, except the field tags
        ID    int
        Title string `json:"-"`
    }

    b, _ := json.MarshalIndent(data(x), "", "  ")
    fmt.Println("main:\n" + string(b))
}
```

Comment: Many many thanks - thanks seems to do what I want. I did not think about including the userlevels as a pointer. Many thanks!